# Link a relation

Tags: sql-server-2008

I stuck in a situtaion and hope I will get a solution here.
Situation is:
A user when wants to join the club he/she has to provide their identification.Lets say a citizen card,passport,driving license etc.
If a user want to get extra services from a club he/she has to provide other documents too like Bank Report,House property etc..

My problem is How to relate these documents .If I have to see the complete doucments of a user I should easily see all the documents given by a user.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you have a `user` table, with a column called `id` which is a unique identifier for a particular user. Then you just need a table called `documents` with a column called `document_id` and a column called `user_id` (this one links to the `id` column in the `user` table).

Then you just do a query like so:

```
SELECT my_column_names FROM user 
LEFT OUTER JOIN documents ON documents.user_id = user.id 
WHERE some_condition
```

You'll probably want to store some information about the documents in the `documents` table, as well as either storing the document itself as a BLOB or just storing a filepath to where the document is saved on your file system; but that's really not part of the question.